# Swap image with text in print

Tags: css, css-sprites

I use sprites to insert images on a page.

```
<div class="sprites logo1"></div>
<div class="sprites logo2"></div>
```

However, when I print the page, unless my settings are changed to print background images, nothing is printed.

I would like to print text instead of logos. Normally I could put image inside div and hide it `@media screen` and show with `@media print` but I'm not sure how to deal with sprites.

Desired outcome for print will be something like:

```
<div>logo1</div>
<div>logo2</div>
```

My CSS for sprites looks lile this:

```
.sprites{
   background: url(../logos.png) no-repeat top left
}
.logo1{
   background-position: 0 0;
   width: 184px;
   height: 57px
}
.logo2{
   background-position: 0 -60px;
   width: 175px;
   height: 34px
}
```

so I thought that by adding this I may get it right:

```
@media print {
   .logo1{ 
      content: url(../logos.png) no-repeat 0 0;
      width: 184px;
      height: 57px
   }
}
```

The problem with this solution, is that it shows an entire sprites image, condensed to the dimensions of the logo. So far it seems that the only solution is to cut the logos and use separate ones for print version, which is a bummer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do something along these lines, making use of the Kellum Method, [as named by Zeldman](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/):

HTML:

```
<div class="sprites logo1">Text Here</div>
<div class="sprites logo2">Text Here</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen {
  .sprites {
    background: url(../logos.png) no-repeat top left
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .logo1{
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 184px;
    height: 57px
  }
  .logo2{
    background-position: 0 -60px;
    width: 175px;
    height: 34px
  }
}

@media print {
  .sprites {
    /* style this text as desired for print */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Change your code to something like this:

```
<div class="sprites logo1"><h1>Logo 1 Text</h1></div>
<div class="sprites logo2"><h2>Logo 2 Text</h1></div>
```

Then in your print media CSS:

```
.sprites .logo1 { background-color:white !important ; background-image:none !important }
.sprites .logo2 { background-color:white !important ; background-image:none !important }
```

And in your screen CSS:

```
.sprites .logo1 h1 { display:none !important }
.sprites .logo2 h2 { display:none !important }
```

That way on screens, the text is hidden and when printing, the text is visible and the sprite images are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add the desired print text to the HTML, like this:

```
<div class="sprites logo1">Logo 1</div>
```

Then, in your screen CSS, add a negative `text-indent`, which will effectively hide the text when viewing it on a screen.

```
.logo1 {
  text-indent: -9999px; 
}
```

In your print CSS, reset the `text-indent` to 0 to display it.

```
.logo1 {
    text-indent: 0;
}
```